# AngularJS background update models - best practice

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a script that get document and positions of this document in some interval in background. Positions are displayed by ng-repeat, and some field of positions are aditable. When I'am writind new data to my position field, all is lost, becouse in apper new version of document and positions.

Is posible to check then input/textares is focused and merge data from scope and new data?

My script:

```
$scope.getDoc = function (id) {
    DocFactory.get(id).then(function (doc) {

        $scope.doc = doc;

        PosFactory.getPos(id).then(function (pos) {
            $scope.pos = pos;
        });

    });
}

// when app start
$scope.getDoc();

// when synced
$rootScope.$on("synced",function(){
    $scope.getDoc();
});

$scope.addDesc = function(pos, description) {
    pos.description = description;
    PosFactory.getPos(pos.id, pos).then(function () {
        $scope.getDoc();
    });
}

<div ng-repeat="p in pos">
    <form ng-init="description=p.desc">
        <textarea ng-model="description"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" 
            ng-click="addDesc(p, description)">
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Show your html code also.

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify index in `track by` part of [ng-repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#tracking-and-duplicates)

Comment: The problem appears when $broadcast('synced') is emit and I have new content in textarea. Calling $scope.getDoc() ereses chenged content.